# How do I get vlc via X11-over-ssh to display the right font, instead of black rectangles only?

Tags: ssh, fonts, xorg, vlc-media-player, x11-forwarding

I'm running vlc on my Arch Linux box, forwarded via X11/ssh to my Mac. All characters in the application have been replaced by a black rectangle, so I can't read any labels. I would guess that vlc wants some font that the Mac doesn't know about. How would I fix this?

```
mac> ssh -Y my-arch-box
my-arch-box> vlc
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: The fonts used will need to be installed on your local system, not the remote system.

Comment: How do I find out what fonts it wants?

Comment: And why doesn't it fall back to at least some working fonts. I thought Xorg was capable of that.